# python django how to only show the information about an individual employee when I click on his name

Tags: python, django

I'm new to python django, trying to create an employee records project, on the django admin site I added some employees and their information, on the django site, I had the hyperlink for the individual employee, but when I click on the individual name, the next page comes all the employees information instead of the particular one, how can I only make it come out the information of the employee I click? Please help, thank you!

models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

class Employee(models.Model):
    '''An employee's information.'''
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hire_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return a string representation of the model.'''
        return self.full_name
        return self.address
        return self.city
        return self.state
        return self.zip
        return self.hire_date
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Employee

def index(request):
    '''The home page for employee_record.'''
    return render(request, 'employee_records/base.html')

def employees(request):
    '''Shows all employees'''
    employees = Employee.objects.order_by('full_name')
    context = {'employees': employees}
    return render(request, 'employee_records/employees.html', context)

def employee(request, employee_id):
    '''Show a single employee and all his records.'''
    employee = Employee.objects.get(id=employee_id)
    objects = Employee.objects.all
    context = {'employee': employee, 'objects': objects}
    return render(request, 'employee_records/employee.html', context)
```

urls.py

```
'''Defines URL patterns for employee_records.'''
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'employee_records'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.employees, name='employees'),

    # Detail page for a single employee
    path('employees/<int:employee_id>/', views.employee, name='employee'),
]
```

base.html

```
<p>
  <a href="{% url 'employee_records:employees' %}">Employee-Record</a>
</p>

{% block content %}{% endblock content %}
```

employees.py

```
{% extends 'employee_records/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <ul>
    {% for employee in employees %}   

     <li>
        <a href="{% url 'employee_records:employee' employee.id %}">{{ employee }}</a>
     </li>

    {% empty %}

    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

{% endblock content %}
```

employee.html

```
{% extends 'employee_records/employees.html' %}

{% block content %}

  <p>{{ employee }}

    {% for object in objects %}
      <li>{{ object.full_name }}</li>
      <li>{{ object.address }}</li>
      <li>{{ object.city }}</li>
      <li>{{ object.state }}</li>
      <li>{{ object.zip }}</li>
      <li>{{ object.hire_date }}</li>

    {% empty %}

      <li>There are no records for this employee yet.</li>

    {% endfor %}
  </p>

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: You are explicitly going through all employees with `{% for object in objects %}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
models.py

# you should have only one return statement

class Employee(models.Model):
    '''An employee's information.'''
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    hire_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        '''Return a string representation of the model.'''
        return self.full_name


views.py

# you have to change employee function

def employee(request, employee_id):
    '''Show a single employee'''
    try:
        employee = Employee.objects.get(id=employee_id)
    except Employee.DoesNotExist:
        employee = None

    context = {'employee': employee}
    return render(request, 'employee_records/employee.html', context)



employee.html

{% extends 'employee_records/employees.html' %}

{% block content %}

{% if employee %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ employee.full_name}}</li>
        <li>{{ employee.address}}</li>
        <li>{{ employee.city}}</li>
        <li>{{ employee.state}}</li>
        <li>{{ employee.zip}}</li>
        <li>{{ employee.hire_date}}</li>
    </ul>
{% endif %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

other way to achieve it is with a built in get_object_or_404 method

## individual view

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def employee(request, employee_id):
    employee = get_object_or_404(Employee, employee_id=employee_id)
    context = {'employee': employee}
    return render(request, 'employee_records/employee.html', context)
```